# Applet not running in browser

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I'm developing an Applet which uses 3rd party libraries. It works correctly if I run it from Eclipse but if I launch it from the browser I get a runtime error.

Here's my code html:

```
<applet code='it.witbit.SignApplet.class' 
        codebase="http://localhost/applet2/"
        archive='AppletFirma.jar' 
        >
```

The `.jar` file is correctly found together with the SignApplet.class. However there's a runtime error:

```
network: Connessione a http://localhost/applet2/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator.class con proxy=DIRECT
basic: eccezione: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator
```

All the jars needed by the Applet are in the same folder as AppletFirma.jar, that is applet2 folder of localhost (set as the codebase). 
The manifest contains just a simple declaration:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

and I've exported the Applet from Eclipse without including any external jars.
Any idea on what's going on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Export the Applet from Eclipse and **do** include the external jars. I don't believe the browser will go searching for external jar files for your Applet.

Comment: Ok, so I did export the external jars with the applet itself. The html and the manifest (generated by eclipse) have no changes but now the applet jar has a lib sudfolder with all the required jars. I got the same error. How should I change manifest or html to make it work?!

Comment: Applets don't search a lib subfolder for jar files. Extract the classes from the jar files into your applet jar.

Comment: Hello Elliott, I've done as you said now I got the following error:  `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.ext.dirs" "read")`